# SIMPLEX system of Latex equations

Tags: latex, equation

I want to emulate this in LaTeX code as an equation.

[image]

```
\usepackage{spalign}
\[
  \spalignsys{
  \text{Maximizar} \hspace{4mm} z=c_1x_1+c_2x_2+\dots+c_nx_n ;
   \text{Sujeto a:} ;
\hspace{4mm} a_{11}x_1+a_{12}x_2+\dots+a_{1n}x_n \leq b_1;
x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n \geq 0  }
\]
```

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/587254/multiple-curly-braces-in-align

Comment: I have looked at it and it does not solve my problem. I can't emulate the image above.

Comment: The please add the code you tried to your question.

Comment: I have edited the question with my try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the same technique as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/587258/36296 :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
\left\{\begin{array}{lc}
\text{Maximizar} & z=c_1x_1+c_2x_2+\dots+c_nx_n\\
 \text{Sujeto a:}& \\
&a_{11}x_1+a_{12}x_2+\dots+a_{1n}x_n \leq b_1\\
& x+1+2+3\\
\end{array}\right.
\]
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but it is not centred. How can I centre it all?

Comment: See the updated answer